# C socket server: What's the right way to read all of an unknown length XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: sockets, xmlhttprequest, packet, recv

I have a simple XMLHttpRequest handler written in C. It reads and processes requests coming from a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest send() running in a browser.

The parent process accepts incoming connections and forks a child process for each incoming connection to read and process the data.

It works perfectly for most requests, but fails in some cases (apparently related to the network infrastructure between the client and the server) if the request is over about 2 kB in length. I'm assuming that the request is being broken into multiple packets somewhere between the browser and my socket server.

I can't change the request format, but I can see the request being sent and verify the content. The data is a 'GET' with an encoded URI that contains a 'type' field. If the type is 'file', the request could be as long as 3 kB, otherwise it's a couple of hundred bytes at most. 'File' requests are rare - the user is providing configuration data to be written to a file on the server. All other requests work fine, and any 'file' requests shorter than about 2 kB work fine.

What's the preferred technique for ensuring that I have all of the data in this situation?

Here's the portion of the parent that accepts the connection and forks the child (non-blocking version):

```
  for (hit = 1;; hit++) {
    length = sizeof(cli_addr);
    if ((socketfd = accept4(listensd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &length, SOCK_NONBLOCK)) < 0){
    //if ((socketfd = accept(listensd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &length)) < 0){
      exit(3);
    }
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
      exit(3);
    } else {
      if (pid == 0) { /* child */
        //(void) close(listensd);
        childProcess(socketfd, hit); /* never returns.  Close listensd when done*/
      } else { /* parent */
        (void) close(socketfd);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the portion of the child process that performs the initial recv(). In the case of long 'file' requests, the child's first socket recv() gets about 1700 bytes of payload followed by the browser-supplied connection data.

```
  ret = recv(socketfd, recv_data, BUFSIZE, 0); // read request
  if (ret == 0 || ret == -1) { // read failure stop now
    sprintf(sbuff, "failed to read request: %d", ret);
    logger(&shm, FATAL, sbuff, socketfd);
  }
  recv_data[ret] = 0;
  len = ret;
```

If the type is 'file', there could be more data. The child process never gets the rest of the data. If the socket is blocking, a second read attempt simply hangs. If the socket is non-blocking (as in the snippet below) all subsequent reads return -1 with error 'Resource temporarily unavailable' until it times out:

```
// It's a file. Could be broken into multiple blocks. Try second read
sleep(1);
ret = recv(socketfd, &recv_data[len], BUFSIZE, 0); // read request
while (ret != 0){
  if (ret > 0){
    recv_data[len+ret] = 0;
    len += ret;
  } else {
    sleep(1);
  }
  ret = recv(socketfd, &recv_data[len], BUFSIZE, 0); // read request
}
```

I expected that read() would return 0 when the client closes the connection, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: Non-blocking sockets raise an error when the data isn't available immediately. It basically means "Try again later." You can use `select` to determine if a socket is ready to be read/written, or don't use a non-blocking socket.

If you never get more data, then it's possible that the server isn't sending the data correctly.  Provide a reproducible example to debug further.

Comment: "*If you never get more data, then it's possible that the server isn't sending the data correctly*" - or, more likely, that you are not reading/processing the data correctly, and so don't know when to STOP reading when the end of a request is reached. The code shown is definitely NOT the correct way to read requests from an XMLHttpRequest client.

Comment: _"and so don't know when to STOP reading when the end of a request is reached."_ - exactly, but also I don't know when I need to read more. The return values from read() don't seem to help. Are there socket options or content header tricks that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

A GET request only has a head and no body (well, almost always), so you have everything the client has sent as soon as you have the request head, and you know when you have read the whole request head when you read a blank line i.e. two returns (and no sooner or later).

If the client sends just a part, without the blank line, you are supposed to wait for the rest. I would put a time-out on that and reject the whole request if it takes too long.

BTW there are still browsers out there, and maybe some proxies as well, with a URL length limit of about 2000 characters.